# Variance of joint hypergeometric distribution with proportion as continuous random variable

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

**Question**
A quality control plan that calls for randomly selecting three items from the daily production
(assumed large) of a certain machine and observing the number of defectives. The proportion
$p$ of defectives produced by the machine varies from day to day and has a uniform distribution
on the interval $(0,1)$. Find the variance of the number of defectives among the three sampled.
(a) $2.5 $ (b) $1.25 $
(c) $3$
(d) $2.75 $
(e) none of the above.

**My attempt**

The joint distribution is given by $f(p,m) = \cfrac{{1000p \choose m}{ 1000-1000p \choose 3 - m}}{1000 \choose 3}$, where $p$ is the proportion and $m$ is the number of defectives. To find the variance of $M$, I need to find the the marginal distribution of $f_M$, and thence compute a simple discrete variance. The trouble is I don't know how to evaluate $f_M(m) = \int_{0}^1f(p,m) \ dp$ because of the factorial element. Also, while intuitively I understand the importance of $p$ being uniform, I'm missing its relevance in the calculations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to go through such computations.  Just apply the law of total variance.  The hierarchical model is
$$P \sim \operatorname{Uniform}(0,1), \\ D \mid P \sim \operatorname{Binomial}(n = 3, P),$$ where $P$ is the proportion of defective items for a given day, and $D$ is the number of defective items in the sample of $n = 3$.  Note your use of the hypergeometric distribution is inappropriate; you do not explain why $1000p$ is a parameter for such a model, and more importantly, although the sample is technically drawn without replacement, the population is assumed to be large enough that the probability of any given item in the sample being defective does not depend on whether the other items in the sample are defective.

We are asked to compute $\operatorname{Var}[D]$, the unconditional variance of the number of defective items in the sample.  By the law of total variance, this is $$\operatorname{Var}[D] = \operatorname{E}[\operatorname{Var}[D \mid P]] + \operatorname{Var}[\operatorname{E}[D \mid P]].$$  The conditional expectation $\operatorname{E}[D \mid P]$ is simply $nP$, and the conditional variance $\operatorname{Var}[D \mid P]$ is $nP(1-P)$, as $D \mid P$ is binomial.  So the above becomes $$\operatorname{Var}[D] = \operatorname{E}[nP(1-P)] + \operatorname{Var}[nP] = n (\operatorname{E}[P]-\operatorname{E}[P^2]) + n^2 \operatorname{Var}[P].$$  For $P$ uniform on $(0,1)$, we have $\operatorname{E}[P] = 1/2$, and $\operatorname{E}[P^2] = 1/3$, and $\operatorname{Var}[P] = 1/12$, thus $$\operatorname{Var}[D] = 3(1/2 - 1/3) + 3^2(1/12) = \frac{5}{4}.$$